# Kohana orm order asc/desc?

Tags: php, sorting, orm, kohana

I heed two variables storing the maximum id from a table, and the minimum id from the same table.

the first id is easy to be taken ,using find() and a query like

```
        $first = Model::factory('product')->sale($sale_id)->find();
```

but how can i retrieve the last id? is there a sorting option in the Kohana 3 ORM?
thanks!

Comment: Don't ask for it to retrieve rows just to get the id, just `SELECT MAX(id), MIN(id) FROM table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing like this, I suppose you'll be :

- selecting all lines of your table that correspond to your condition
- fetching all those lines from MySQL to PHP
- to, finally, only work with one of those lines

Ideally, you should be doing an SQL query that uses the `MAX()` or the `MIN()` function -- a bit like this :

```
select max(your_column) as max_value
from your_table
where ...
```

Not sure how to do that with Kohana, but [this topic on its forum](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/159/database-query-for-max/p1) looks interesting.

Comment: i've seen this topic. the idea is that i don't want to 'hardcode' the query in SQL, i was wodering if i can do this max select just using the plain kohana ORM. but i think this is not possible. thank you!

Comment: Oh ; sorry, I can't help you more, about that :-(

Answer (score 6):

1. Yes, you can sort resulting rows in ORM with `order_by($column, $order)`. For example, `->order_by('id', 'ASC')`.
2. Use QBuilder to get a specific values:

> ```
>   public function get_minmax() 
>   {
>       return DB::select(array('MAX("id")', 'max_id'),array('MIN("id")', 'min_id'))
>                  ->from($this->_table_name)
>                  ->execute($this->_db); 
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

The problem could actually be that you are setting order_by after find_all. You should put it before. People do tend to put it last.
This way it works.

```
     $smthn = ORM::factory('smthn')
        ->where('something', '=', something)
        ->order_by('id', 'desc')
        ->find_all();
```